# Dissociation rates: trans-effect rule in square planar complexes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, organometallic-compounds

In lecture, the trans-effect was described.

A ligand $L^t$ with a higher trans-effect as $L$ (cis to $L^t$) leads to a faster dissociation of ligand $L^d$ (trans to $L^t$). I would expect that the attacking ligand $B$ is needed to make a stronger bond as the leaving ligand $L^d$ did.

[image]

In order to see if these assumptions are always valid in planar quadratic systems I've set up following problem according to the given trans-effect order:

[image]

$\ce{CO}$ has a stronger trans-effect as $\ce{CH3-}$ and therefore the ligand trans to $\ce{CO}$ will be exchanged faster as trans to the $\ce{CH3-}$. But the leaving group $\ce{I-}$ would also have a higher trans-effect as $\ce{Cl-}$ so I wouldn't expect a substitution in b). Are these statements correct?

Answer (score 2):

First off, there are two nice articles on the trans effect on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_effect) and [LibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/?title=Core/Inorganic_Chemistry/Organometallic_Chemistry/Fundamentals/The_trans//cis_Effects_%26_Influences) that are worth reading.

You need to remember that there are two factors leading to the *trans* effect:

- Weakening the $\ce{Pt-X}$ bond *trans* to another group (i.e., a structural effect)
- Stabilizing the 5-coordinate transition state, since substitution reactions in square planar complexes are generally associative. (i.e., a kinetic effect)

(a) I don't think the $\ce{I-}$ will substitute for the $\ce{NH3}$ group. Instead, I think the $\ce{CO}$ "wins" the *trans* effect "competition" and so the *trans* $\ce{CH3-}$ will be replaced by the $\ce{I-}$.

Next, substitution with the $\ce{Cl-}$ should replace the $\ce{I-}$.

[image]

Now your second question seems to be if you'll actually get a substitution with $\ce{Cl-}$ since $\ce{I-}$ has a greater *trans* effect. Yes, you will. All of these are in equilibrium, so if you generate a lot of $\ce{I-}$ that can substitute back (and get starting material). But you'll definitely get the Cl-substituted product too if you separate the reaction mixture.

Indeed, the prototypical example for the *trans* effect is synthesis of *trans*-platin or *cis*-platin, starting from either $\ce{[PtCl4]^{-2}}$ or $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4]^{+2}}$. Even though $\ce{NH3}$ has a smaller *trans* effect, you can synthesize *cis*-platin from $\ce{[PtCl4]^{-2}}$ and substituting two $\ce{Cl-}$ with $\ce{NH3}$.

Comment: The trans effect on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_effect) is quite easy to understand because there are only two different groups involved. Did I correctly understood; for step a) you've only chosen the ligand which has the highest trans effect? I'd argue that in the starting material $\ce{CO}$ trans to $\ce{CH3-}$ is more stable as $\ce{CO}$ trans to $\ce{I-}$ because of the better donor properties of $\ce{CH3-}$ there is a better push-pull-stabilization. But I think my argument is wrong because it is a thermodynamic argument and not a kinetic argument.

Comment: The unfortunate problem with ***trans*** effect is that there is a thermodynamic *structural* effect and a *kinetic* effect. Yes, you pick the leaving group *trans* to the strongest substituent. I'm not sure I follow the rest of your argument here.

Comment: I'd argue that in the starting material $\ce{CO}$ trans to $\ce{CH3-}$ is more stable as $\ce{CO}$ trans to $\ce{I−}$ because of the better donor properties of $\ce{CH3-}$ there is a better push-pull-stabilization that means $\ce{CO}$ favors electrons from a strong trans placed donor for a good $\Pi$ Backbonding. The methyl group acts already as the better donor as iodine does.

Comment: That's true, but besides the point. The $\ce{CO}$ group won't substitute in either case.

Comment: I'm not sure if I pointed it out clearly: It's no question, $\ce{CO}$ will not get substituted. Although the trans placed methyl is more stable as the iodine so I would not propose that the methyl will get substituted by an iodine.

Comment: @laminin As I said, all these ligands are labile, so it's a question of where the $\ce{I-}$ will go, not whether it will or not. Based on the *trans* effects, the methyl will be replaced.

Comment: all right. (The question, where the $\ce{I-}$ will go: I believe the negative charge is mire stable on soft iodine instead of hard methylanion, but may be this is wrong.) I guess according to trans effect I understood it in this way: 1.) In normal cases always the ligand with highest trans-effect dictates the trans placed substituent to leave. 2.) The trans-effect strength of the attacking nucleophile is not important to expect which ligand gets substituted.

Comment: Did I understood your rules correctly: In normal cases always the ligand with highest trans-effect (here in A) and B) it's the $\ce{CO}$) dictates that the trans played substituent has to leave? Do you know an example where this is not the case, do you know an exception where the 5-coordinate transitionstate overrules the dissociation of the ligand trans to the ligand with the highest trans-effect?

Comment: @laminin That's the point. Unfortunately, people call "trans effect" for two different things, but the key in your question is the kinetic effect on the 5-coordinate transition state. So there's no "exception" because these are one and the same thing. The substituent trans to the highest "kinetic trans" effect will leave.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison thank you for the answer! Not completely related to this question, but I wonder: does trans-effect (structural) exist for complexes dominated by electrostatic interactions (i.e. "hard") and not orbital mixing?

Comment: @substitutedbutadiene - Please [ask a new question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) rather than leave it buried in the questions

Comment: @GeoffHutchison How "Weakening the Pt−X bond trans to another group" leads to a lower activation energy? In many textbooks is explained by saying that it destabilizes the ground state of the molecule by weakening the bond Pt-X. But one could also argue that the Y-Pt bond is now stronger (Y is greater σ donor) so these two effects should cancel. Could we say better than this destabilization is depicted in the transition state because now the Pt-X bond breaks easier?