# Trans effect on square planar complex

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

We've learnt about the trans effect but I have a question regarding how this plays a role with water in the equation.

**trans-effect**:

$$\ce{H2O < NH3 < Cl-}$$

Based on this, given *cis*-$\ce{[Pt(NH3)2Cl2]}$, if you were to add water to form a dicationic complex, would a substituion reaction occur between all the substituents, and then $\ce{Cl-}$ reacts again to form the trans-complex?

Since water has a weaker trans effect than both $\ce{NH3}$ AND $\ce{Cl-}$, I can't imagine that a cis-complex would form as any cis-combination of $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ has a stronger trans effect than any combination of $\ce{H2O / Cl- / NH3}$.

Are there any other kinetic / electronegativity factors that I am missing?

Comment: Just to clarify.. You're asking if you replace both $\ce{Cl-}$ ligands with two $\ce{H2O}$ ligands, what would you get? I indicate the chloro ligand here because you said "dictation". I'm just trying to get the sequence of reactions (i.e., first one, then two $\ce{H2O}$ to get $\ce{[Pt(H2O)2(NH3)2]}$ and then react with $\ce{Cl}$

Comment: It's really not clear to me what sequence of reactions is intended in your question, making it *very* hard to answer. If you list each reaction, I can probably help.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/18409/5017